# Powershell AD Users CSV report with ADPropertyValueCollection Error

Tags: powershell, csv

Got a loop going through AD users that will delete users that are over 90 days old.
I want to pull a report of all the deleted users in to a CSV.
In a few fields of the CVS I get the Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPRopertyValueCollection

The code is this

```
 Get all users in that have not logged on within 
# 60 days in "Active Directory" and Disable them 
# 
# Get the Current Date 
LogInfo("START OF LOG FILE")
LogInfo("Compare Date : Getting date")
$COMPAREDATE=GET-DATE

# Number of Days to check back.
LogInfo("Set Disable Time : Settings Number of days to Disable to 60")
$NumberDays=(get-date).addDays(-60)
#$then = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

# Number of Days to check for REALLY Stale accounts 
# Our sample here is taking "OldAccounts" and pumping up 
# 30 more days.  
#Therefore 90 days old accounts that haven't logged in should be purged 
# 
LogInfo("Set Delete Time : Setting number of days to Delete to 90")
$DeleteDate=$NumberDays+30

# We have certain "Override fields" that bypass a delete 
# happening.  If the "Notes" field in A/D contains the 
# EXACT Override phrase ANYWHERE (in this case it is the 
# word ***OVERRIDE*** and it IS case sensitive 
# The account will NEVER be deleted (unless of course you remove 
# Word from the Notes field 
#
LogInfo("Set Override key word")
#$OverRide='***OVERRIDE***' 

# The other override field is if 
# the OnLeave details are in the Description 
# Field in A/D.  this allows for a User who is 
# Not gone (IE: Contractor / Student) but may 
# Return to have the account disabled and 
# Left alone until they return.  The words here are 
# simple On Leave Until and can be ANYWHERE in the 
# Description Field in A/D 
# 
LogInfo("Set On Leave override key word")
$OnLeave='On Leave Until'

# Organizational Unit to search â€“ This is in the fictional domain of 
# â€˜Contoso.localâ€™ in the OU of Users under the Business OU on the Root 
# of the Contoso A/D 
# 
LogInfo("Set OU Path : Setting OU path to Test OU")
$OU='OU=Users,OU=Test,DC=corporate,DC=nzpost,DC=co,DC=nz'

# Get all users not active within the specified range and disable the accounts in Active Directory 
# 
# We store them away as a variable since we're going to examine the list a few times. 
LogInfo("Listing User accounts that is 60 days old")
$LISTOFACCOUNTS=Get-ADUser -Property lastlogondate -SearchBase $OU -Filter {lastLogonDate -lt $NumberDays}
# 
# Any account not logged in within the short range gets Disabled in AD 
# 
LogInfo("Disabling user accounts 60 days old")
$LISTOFACCOUNTS | DISABLE-ADACCOUNT -WhatIf

# Pull up a new list.   Really old accounts 
# 
#$LISTOFPOTENTIALDELETES=$LISTOFACCOUNTS | where { $_.LastLogon.AddDays($DeleteDate) -gt $CURRENTDATE } 
$LISTOFPOTENTIALDELETES=Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -Property Lastlogondate -Filter {lastlogondate -lt $DeleteDate}

# Secondary compare is more interesting.  If the accounts are VERY stale, they get deleted UNLESS special keywords 
# are in place 
# 
FOREACH ($USER in $LISTOFPOTENTIALDELETES) { 


        Get-ADUser -Identity $USER -Properties * | Select @{ Name = 'ADsPath'; Expression = { $_.ADsPath -join ';'; }; },cn,givenName,lastLogonDate,description, profilePath, homeDirectory, `
            @{ Name = 'mail'; Expression = { $_.mail -join ';'; }; }, @{ Name = 'publicDelegates'; Expression = { $_.publicDelegates -join ';'; }; }, whenCreated, company, manager, employeeID, `
            @{ Name = 'memberof'; Expression = { $_.memberof -join ';'; }; }  | Export-CSV "E:\Damo\_UserList.csv" -Append  

    IF (($USER.Notes -notlike '*'+$OVERRIDE+'*') -and ($USER.Description -notlike '*'+$OnLeave+'*')) 
    { 

        LogInfo("$USER.SamAccountName Deleted") 
        WRITE-HOST $USER.SamAccountName 'Deleted' 
        REMOVE-ADOBJECT $USER.SamAccountName -whatif 

    } 
    ELSEIF ($USER.Notes -like '*'+$OVERRIDE+'*') 
        { 
            LogInfo("$USER.SamAccountName Not removed due to Administrative Override")
            WRITE-HOST $USER.SamAccountName 'Not removed due to Administrative Override'  
         } 
        ELSE 
        { 
            LogInfo("$USER.SamAccountName Not removed - Presently on Leave")
            WRITE-HOST $USER.SamAccountName 'Not removed - Presently on Leave' 
        } 

#Get-ADUser -Identity $USER -Properties * | Select ADsPath,cn,givenName,lastLogonDate,description, profilePath, homeDirectory, @{ Name = 'mail'; Expression = { $_.mail -join ';'; }; }, 
    #publicDelegates, whenCreated, company, manager, employeeID, memberof | Export-CSV "E:\Folder\_UserList.csv" -Append
} 

$users = get-aduser -SearchBase $OU -Properties userPrincipalName,lastlogonDate,description,mail,profilePath,HomeDirectory -filter {userPrincipalName -like "*"} 
$csv = foreach($user in $users){ 

    $grp = get-adprincipalgroupmembership $user 
    Foreach($group in $grp){ 
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 
            #MemberOf = $user.memberof[0]
            Group = $group.Name 
            User = $user.SamAccountName 
            GivenName = $user.givenName
            Surname = $User.Surname
            LastLogon = $user.lastlogondate
            Description = $User.Description
            Mail = $User.Mail
            ProfilePath = $User.profilePath
            HomeDir = $User.homeDirectory
            } 
        } 
} 

$csv | Export-csv E:\Folder\DeletedUsersInfo.csv
```

How do I get the MemberOf to populate in the CSV, so it shows all the group for that user

I have two loops there as I was trying to get one to work, so it just shows the memberof groups without the full OU Path.

Any help would be fantastic.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that some Active Directory attributes are collections/arrays. For example, a user can have multiple e-mail aliases in the `mail` attribute. In order to display this in a CSV file, you must pre-process the information before it can be represented as a single string.

To demonstrate the "issue" using a simple example, consider the following:

```
$arr = @(1,2,3);
$arr.ToString();
```

The result looks like this:

```
System.Object[]
```

To resolve this, you will need to augment the objects before they are passed into the `Export-Csv` cmdlet. Fortunately, you can easily do this by using `Select-Object`, with slight modification!

Consider this simple example, which builds on the previous one, by joining the array on a character:

```
$arr = @(1,2,3);
$arr -join ';'
```

The result looks like this:

```
1;2;3
```

Now, applying this to your example, we are going to join an array of items on a character (eg. a semicolon). Here is what it would look like:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $USER -Properties * | Select ADsPath,cn,givenName,lastLogonDate,description, profilePath, homeDirectory, @{ Name = 'mail'; Expression = { $_.mail -join ';'; }; }, publicDelegates, whenCreated, company, manager, employeeID, memberof | Export-CSV "E:\Damo\_UserList.csv" -Append
```

In the above code, the resulting `mail` property would look like the following:

```
email1@domain.com;email2@domain.com;email3@domain.com
```

Since the array data is now represented as a single string, it will export normally to the spreadsheet (CSV file).

Comment: coolio, cheers for that. I have this code now I have updated the main questions

Comment: Sorry the code has gone pair shaped, wanted to know how to get the new code I updated to show all the memberof groupp the user is in. As the CSV only show one group.

Comment: You need to use `$_` not `$group`. `@{ Name = 'memberof'; Expression = { $_.MemberOf -join ';'; }; }`

Comment: That worked, I did that before. Sorry, wanted to get just the group names, not the OU path with the group in it. Have copied all the code I am using, so you can see....ta